# Como tornar um model campo boolean para aceitar somente 1 valor verdadeiro e vários falsos no django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Um exemplo de model endereço de um cliente:

```
class Address(models.Model):

    activate = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=False)

    AddressLine1 = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    AddressLine2 = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    postalCode = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    stateProvinceRegion = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
```

Como eu faço para informar ao banco que o campo "activate" pode ter somente 1 valor do tipo "true" e vários do tipo "false", ou seja, somente posso ter um endereço "ativo"(true) e os demais precisam ficar "desativado"(false).

O cliente precisa ter a liberdade de alterar o seu endereço ativo mas mantendo a mesma regra de somente 1 endereço com status ativo(true) por vez!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Address(models.Model):

    ...

    activate = models.BooleanField(blank=False, null=False, default=False)


    def save(self):
        if self.activate:
            addresses = Address.objects.filter(activate=True)
            for address in addresses:
                address.activate = False
                address.save()
        super().save()
```

[Outros exemplos sobre como resolver o mesmo problema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455126/unique-booleanfield-value-in-django)